# Ignore \n (newline characters)

Tags: string, matlab, newline

I get a string which contains a sentence in two lines :

```
'hello this is my first.
program matlab'
```

and I want to change the sentence to be represend in on line:

```
'hello this is my first.program matlab'
```

How could I do it with matlab ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace all occurrences of `\n` to `''`

```
   myNewSt = strrep(mySt,sprintf('\n'),'');
```

For example, type:

```
   strrep( sprintf('this is my \n string'),sprintf('\n'),'')
```

Comment: What if you want to remove only the (potential) new line at the end of the string and leave all the others?